# Can I run `next build` with different environment variables?

Tags: next.js

I have three environment variables stored in `.env.development`, `.env.staging` and `.env.production` separately. And when I run `next build`, I wish I can choose the environment that I am going to use during the build process. Is that possible?

I have viewed this article:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

And it looks like it can only have two sets of environment variables rather than three. I just want to check if there's a possibility to have three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use as many environments as you please. I personally use the `env-cmd` package, but there are alternatives available as well such as the `dotenv` package.

Setup the build scripts in your `package.json` file like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development next build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production next build"
  }
```